# Cannot Access Report Manager URL in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have developed a couple of reports with the Business Intelligence Developement Studio (BIDS), but I cannot deploy them.  When I select Deploy I am asked for my Credentials.  I have no idea what these credentials are.

I have tried to access the Report Manager URL to see if I can set up these credentials.  That too asks for Credentials but it lets me in by using my windows account log in details (this doesnt work for the aforementioned deployment from BIDS).  However the URL opens with a error message as follows:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The type initializer for 'System.Web.UI.BaseParser' threw an exception.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Home.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.HomePage" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register TagPrefix="MSRS" Namespace="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI" Assembly="ReportingServicesWebUserInterface" %>

Source File: /Reports_SQLE/home.aspx    Line: 1
```

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: Errhm, that almost sounds like your Report Server installation is broken. Do you have the option to repair or even re-install the report server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up on SSRS and opted for Crystal Reports